# position: running(header) is an invalid property value in CSS when convert HTML to PDF using wkhtmltopdf

Tags: css, wkhtmltopdf

I am setting a repeatable header and footer to the pdf file. Here is my code:

```html
<style>
    @page { 
        size: A4 landscape; 
        margin: 0.5cm; 
         @top-center {content: element(footer)}
         @bottom-center {content: element(footer)}
    }
    .header { 
        position: running(header);
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .footer { 
        position: running(footer); 
        width: 100%; 
    }
</style>

<div class="header" id="headerContent" >
    It's header
</div>
<div class="footer" id="footerContent">
    It's footer
</div>
<main> 
Content
</main>
```

But when I preview the HTML code before converting to pdf, it seems that `position: running(header);` not working.
[image]

I guess that the version I used does not support this property in CSS, but I not sure.

Can anyone help me.
Thank you!

Comment: Where did you find position: running(....)? It doesn't look like standard CSS. Are you trying to use some preprocessor?

Comment: https://forum.cuba-platform.com/t/how-to-insert-repeatable-footer-header-blocks-on-pages-of-html-to-pdf-report/1967/4 this is where I found them

Comment: I don’t claim to understand all of that link, but note that to get running headers and footers you seem to have to include the flying saucer project. You have not tagged this. Have you included it?

Comment: actually, I didn't tag it. I will try this one